# How to fix ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using ChildView?

Tags: angular

I have directive that controls sibling component that may or may bot be in the view (it is *ngIfed). I am passing reference to that component using `@ViewChild`. When `*ngIf` resolution is changed `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is thrown. If I understand its nature correctly, it means that some component fields that are bounded in any way to the view did change its state during change detection cycle (literally after ngOnChnges). That seams clear to me, but `@ViewChild` by its nature changes binding during change detection phase (afterViewChecked I belive).

The question is, how to tackle this problem? I have seen suggestions to manually invoke `ChangeDetectorRef#detechChanges()` in `afterViewChecked` or something similar, but that does not feel right to me and at first glance should could cause infinite loop.

I have small demonstration - just click the button https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9thvtm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Template

```
<button (click)="state=!state">toggle state</button>

<div [myDir]="stateDiv" #d="myDir">{{d.hasTestElement}}</div>


<div *ngIf="state" #stateDivMarker>
    Showing state div yessss
</div>
```

Code

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  state = false;

  @ViewChild("stateDivMarker")
  stateDiv;
}

@Directive({
  selector: "[myDir]",
  exportAs: "myDir"
})
export class MyDir {
  @Input("myDir")
  testElement;

  get hasTestElement() {
    return !!this.testElement;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the setter is not setting an undefined value since you're using *ngIf

```
private stateDiv: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('stateDivMarker') set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if(content) {
      this.stateDiv = content;
    }
 }
```

**EDIT**

As an alternative I would suggest using the change detector

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfzp87?file=src/app/app.component.html

*component.ts*

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

toggleState() {
    this.state = !this.state;
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

*component.html*

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<button (click)="toggleState()">toggle state</button>

<div [myDir]="stateDiv" #d="myDir">{{d.hasTestElement}}</div>


<div *ngIf="state" #stateDivMarker>
    Showing state div yessss
</div>
```

Comment: This is logicaly invalid as reference of nonExistent element will be still present in the directive and component itself. hasTestElement will return `true` while it should be false.

Comment: Can you share stackblitz?

Comment: @Antoniossss https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfzp87?file=src/app/app.component.html